# import sqlparse ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlparse'

Tags: python, django, sqlite, pip, sql-parser

I have installed

```
pip install sqlparse
pip3 install sqlparse
conda install sqlparse
```

But still getting sqlparse module error
Why is that?

```
(New4) C:\Users\zesha\Documents\GitHub\django-blog>python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zesha\Documents\GitHub\django-blog\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\zesha\Documents\GitHub\django-blog\manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\zesha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\zesha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\zesha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

  File "C:\Users\zesha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\zesha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\zesha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 214, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\zesha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\zesha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .introspection import DatabaseIntrospection            # isort:skip
  File "C:\Users\zesha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\introspection.py", line 4, in <module>
    import sqlparse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlparse'
```

I am getting the following error.
I am not sure where should I install sqlparse

Comment: Please post error messages always as text that you copy-paste into your question, never post screenshots of errors

Comment: I've updated the post. Please check now

Answer (score 1):

Since you also tried `conda install`, I am supsecting that you have anaconda or miniconda installed. `pip` and `pip3` probably point to the python version managed by `conda`. However, your error message suggests that your script is being executed with a python version that is located at

```
C:\Users\zesha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\
```

To install for that version of python specifically, you could try something like (might need to check that that is actual path to python.exe in that folder):

```
C:\Users\zesha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\python.exe -m pip install sqlparse
```

Alternatively, run your script with the python that is managed by conda